# Is it the microservice's responsibility to validate the API key and JWT token?

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, microservices, api-key

My microservices will be called in 2 ways: 1. by unauthenticated users of a public website. 2. by authenticated users of an internal UI to perform admin functions.

I plan on using OIDC with a JWT token to authenticate API calls made by admin users from the admin UI. The token will have claims in it that the microservice will use to determine if the user is authorized to access this API.

I plan on using an API key from the public facing website for API calls made by unauthenticated users. The microservice will validate the API key in the API request header to determine if the API call is from a trusted source.

**Questions**

- Is this a normal / acceptable way of handling authentication and authorization?
- Is it the microservice's responsibility to evaluate the JWT token and API key?  Every microservice will have to do it in my design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's the responsibility of the microservice to validate the API key and JWT token UNLESS you're using a service mesh.

If you have a number of microservices all interacting directly (sending/receiving calls, discovering new instances, etc) then the microservices need to do this validation. This means each service needs to use a framework/library to implement the verification logic (or copy-paste the code around, which actually does make sense in some scenarios).  They'll also need the JWT public keys distributed and rotated.

If, however, you use proxies/service mesh to handle your network calls, than you can likely delegate this to the proxy to handle.  The Envoy proxy for instance includes a [jwt filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/extensions/filters/http/jwt_authn/v3/config.proto) that can do the JWT decode in the network layer.  Depending on your architecture and service design, handling the decoding in the proxy layer may be a bit easier than implementing it yourself. There are some tradeoffs here though in that you need to deploy and maintain the proxies and potentially re-design your apps to parse the decision (yes/no, admin/unauthed user) from headers or cookies that the proxy sets.